# Exporting Filtered Data from Kendo Grid with Save Window

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid and I had to accomplish the exporting of it's data into Excel format that I acheived through below function.

```
function ExportData() {
    var targetGrid = $('#divSearchGrid').data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = targetGrid.dataSource;

    var dataView = dataSource .view();
    var result = '';

    result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";


        //Defining the headers
        result += "<table><tr><th>Task ID</th><th>Task Description</th><th>Assigned To Name</th></tr>";

        //Filling in the data
        for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>";

            result += "<td>";
            result += dataView[i].TaskID;
            result += "</td>";

            result += "<td>";
            result += dataView[i].TaskDescription;
            result += "</td>";

            result += "<td>";
            result += dataView[i].AssignedToName;
            result += "</td>";

            result += "</tr>";
        }
        result += "</table>";
    aLink.href = result;
    aLink.download = 'exporteddata@.xls';
    aLink.click();
}
```

Problem 1:
If filtering is applied it doesn't take that into account and show all the results . I want only the filtered data to be shown in the grid.

Problem 2:
Right now the download is beginning as and when a user clicks on the Export button which in turn calls this function. I want that it should ask for a saving location before starting downloading the created excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data source before using it's view for exporting in the below manner way:

```
//If we want to show the filtered results
    var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: YourDataDource.data(),
        filter: YourDataDource.filter()
    });
```

and then get the view of the filtered data source

```
filteredDataSource.read();

  var dataView = filteredDataSource .view();
```

I guess it can solve your first problem.

Let me know in case of any problem.

Comment: Hi this is what i was looking for my first problem, it worked perfectly.